# How to simply import in Node? (Typescript version)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Trying the simplest import in Node, but am not being able to get it to work....
(Added "name": "Foo", per suggestions on web.)

**package.json**

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "Foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import foo from './foo';
foo();
```

**foo.ts**

```
export default function foo() {
  console.log("FOO");
}
```

**result**

```
import foo from './foo';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

Comment: Are you running the script using `ts-node` (`npx ts-node ./index.ts`) or `node`?

Comment: How are you making your TypeScript run on Node? Are you transpiling it? Are you using ts-node?

Comment: @user3210641  $ node index.ts

Comment: @Quentin $ node index.ts

Comment: @Oded — That would be the problem. Node.js doesn't support TypeScript.

Comment: Changed the title to TS - adding a new JS version of the same question

Comment: Node by default doesn't use ECMAScript module syntax. you would have to add the line `"type":"module"`` to your package.json file.

Answer (score -1):

remove the line `type: "module"` from the `package.json` and see if that helps. That is because that line activates ES6 Modules for Node.js and you are trying to use commonJS modules, which don't play nicely together.

Comment: Same bad result. Were you able to get your solution to work?
import foo from './foo';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: did you compile your typescript file to javascript?

Comment: @ Schwieriiiiig. Did not, I got the similar problems when doing the same vanilla JS.

Comment: so then 1. compile your typescript source-code with `tsc` to javscript with an approriate tsconfig.json (`tsc --init`) and then run your files again