# How to simply import in Node? (Vanilla JS version) - including type:module

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a JS version of similar (unresolved) TS question.
See: [How to simply import in Node? (Typescript version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70598630/how-to-simply-import-in-node-typescript-version)

Trying the simplest import in Node, but am not being able to get it to work....

**Note!!!** Added  "type": "module" as suggested in [Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)

**package.json**

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "import_js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "dummy project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**index.js**

```
import foo from './foo';
foo();
```

**foo.js**

```
export default function foo() {
  console.log("FOO");
}
```

**result**

```
$ node index.js
/Users/projects/sb/import_js/index.js:1
import foo from './foo';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

Comment: What version of `node` are you running? Please post the result of `node -v`

Comment: v12.16.1 (Adding some meaningless words so that I can post the comment...)

Comment: Well then you should update your installation… [Modules history](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_modules_ecmascript_modules): "*v12.17.0 
Loading ECMAScript modules no longer requires a command-line flag.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by jsfriend comment, check if this is a CommonJS module.
In case it is the following code will do:

**index.js**

```
var foo = require('./foo.js');
foo.foo();
```

**foo.js**

```
function foo() {
  console.log("FOO");
}

exports.foo = foo;
```

Answer (score 3):

After recreating your same three files in a directory by themselves I found that if I change this:

```
import foo from './foo';
```

to this:

```
import foo from './foo.js';
```

Then, it works.  I believe I remember something about ESM modules that says you have to specify the file extension and you can't just use the root name like you can with CommonJS modules.

Using your exact code, recreated in the same three files, running node v16.13.0, making this one change makes it work for me.

---

Now, I did not originally get the same error you got.  I got this error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module xxx import from yyy
```

I wonder if you had a file named just `foo` somehow that it was finding?  If not, something else is still different in your system than mine.

I wonder if you're still trying to use a TypeScript compiler and the TypeScript compile target is set for CommonJS modules?

Because the error you get is somehow indicating that a CommonJS module is getting loaded, but there is no reason for that if given only these three files in a directory by themselves and no compile step of any kind.

Things for you to check.

1. Are you sure that when you run `node`, you're running the plain node executable and not something that Typescript has installed that will try to compile the sources using some default configuration?
2. Are there ANY other files in this directory?  If so, then isolate these three files into their own directory where there are no other package.json files anywhere in the parent tree.
3. Try executing the test.js file from the same directory (so using the same package.json) below and see what it outputs:

Sample file:

```
// test.js
let foundDirname = typeof __dirname === "string";
let foundModule = typeof module === "object";

console.log("found __dirname", foundDirname);
console.log("found module", foundModule);

if (foundDirname && foundModule) {
    console.log("appears to be a CommonJS module")
} else {
    console.log("appears to be an ESM module");
}
```

This should tell you whether it is treating your file as a CommonJS module or an ESM module.

Run this test file with:

```
node test.js
```

Comment: [Mandatory file extensions](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions)

Comment: @GOTO0 - Yeah, there is an experimental command line flag `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` to enable loading without file extensions.  But, without that, they are required for ESM code.

Comment: @oded - Added more debugging options to my answer to help you troubleshoot.  My best guess is that something in your environment is changing your configuration to a CommonJS project before the first file is run so node thinks your files should be CommonJS.  Most likely culprit is something TypeScript related installed in your environment.  Perhaps the command `node` has been replaced and that isn't vanilla nodejs.

Comment: @oded - Where'd you go?  I was working on this with you and even produced a test file for you to run and you seem to have disappeared.

Comment: Sorry Sir! Was traveling. Thanks for your effort! Created a git repo with your suggestion, still does not work for me :( git clone https://frmOded@bitbucket.org/frmOded/import_js.git

Comment: The test script yields the message below. In order to run it, one must remove the "type": "module", line from pacakge.json.    found __dirname true found module true appears to be a CommonJS module

Comment: Removing/Adding the "type":"module" line toggles between the 2 different ERROR messages.

Answer (score -2):

Simply import like this.

```
const foo = require("./foo.js");
```

Comment: The whole point of the question is to create an ESM module-based project - NOT to use `require()` in a CommonJS module.

Comment: Okay, I agree with you.
Any one from this will works either you can use import and give the relative path of the file with extension or you can use the require with the relative path of the file with extension.